# Equals method return false on same string value from differnt object

Tags: java

Example ::

```
List<KeyValueDTO> keyValueList = new ArrayList<>();
KeyValueDTO keyValueDTO;
    for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
        Map<String, Object> searchMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("search");


            keyValueDTO = new KeyValueDTO();
            String key = (String) map.get("data"); // here key = userFirstName userLastName
            keyValueDTO.setKey(key);

            keyValueDTO.setValue((String) searchMap.get("value"));
            keyValueList.add(keyValueDTO);
    }

    for (KeyValueDTO keyValueDTO1 : keyValueList) {
        System.out.println("key :: " + keyValueDTO1.getKey());

        System.out.println("result : " + keyValueDTO1.getKey().equals("userFirstName userLastName"));  // It must print true for key = userFirstName userLastName
    }
```

Result ::

key :: userFirstName userLastName
result : false  //It must be true?

I am trying this on AWS Lambda JAVA 8.

I tried the following code for test

```
    String s = new String("TEST");
    String b = "TEST";

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("TEST");

    String n = null;
    for (Object object : list) {
        n = (String) object;
    }

    System.out.println(list.contains("TEST"));
    System.out.println(s.equals(b));
    System.out.println(b.equals(n));
    System.out.println(s.equals(n));
    System.out.println(n.equals("TEST"));
```

RESULT :: 
        true
        true
        true
        true
        true

It seems to be a weird behavior or it can be a small mistake which I am not getting.

Comment: I trust you have used your favourite debugger to check for miscellaneous spaces, unicode characters, and the like?

Comment: `"key".equals("userFirstName userLastName")` is `false`. are you sure that both values match?

Comment: Without seeing your input it's impossible to make an answer. An assumption would be that your Strings have a `BOM` at the start of the line ruining your input. You can try to do a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(keyValueDTO1.getKey().getBytes()))` to check for invisible characters.

Comment: Are you sure that they are the same strings (non typo). And is the whitspace a real whitespace, not an 'nbsp' ?

Comment: Just to make sure - Does `keyValueDTO1.getKey()` return a `String`?

Comment: Thanks @Ben it helps as there was an extra space in the middle of the string, but surprisingly it was not showing on the java side. System.out.println("key :: " + alertKeyValueDTO1.getKey()) this gives the following output "userFirstName userLastName" (single space in middle) but  System.out.println("invisible "+ Arrays.toString(alertKeyValueDTO1.getKey().getBytes())) prints [117, 115, 101, 114, 70, 105, 114, 115, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101, 32, 32, 117, 115, 101, 114, 76, 97, 115, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101] which shows 2 whitespaces(char 32)